# XAML to C# Converter

Tags: c#, xaml

I need help to convert XAML TO C# in the following code.
It was working fine at the design time. But I want to assign the values in the runtime.

Here is the XAML code:

`< Image UITest:SupportAnimatedGIFBehviour.SupportAnimatedGif="True"/>`

And the full source is in the following website:

http://eladm.wordpress.com/2009/04/02/animated-gif-support-behavior/

Comment: What do you mean convert to C#? Are you converting it to using a 2D API?  Also, there really is no question here, IMO, but a hope for help.  You may want to show what you are trying to do, without expecting people to d/l and wander through your code, but give us the high-level picture, and if there is some snippet that is a problem then share that also.

Comment: Hello James,
Convert to C# means i am looking for Same XAML code in C#. Because i need to set the values dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

For this XAML:

```
<Image Name="myImage"/>
```

Use this C# code:

```
SupportAnimatedGIFBehviour.SetSupportAnimatedGif( myImage, true );
```

Comment: No jyoung. It is not working. It is not behaving as like design mode. ie., In design mode it showing the animation in the Gif. But if we setsupport fun then it shows only first frame.

Comment: I place an animated gif on a blank WPF window, call the code, and it worked. Does it fail in this simple case for you?

Answer (score -1):

Use http://xamlt.com/ to convert any XAML Code to C#

Comment: Website is dead.